# dynamically load src for audio and stop after src does not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, error-handling, html5-audio

I have songs called *song_1*, *song_2*, *song_3* etc. I want them to play immediately after the previous has finished. That's why I have an "ended" function which plays the next song automatically (works fine so far). The amount of songs I have is obtained dynamically, so I can't tell to stop loading the next src by hardcoding. But when a src does not exist, I get an error, and I cannot replay the songs after finishing etc. How can I prevent this error?

HTML:

```
<audio id="audio">
        <source id="mp3Source" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

JQuery:

```
var audio = $("#audio");
var src = "audio/song_";
var countSongs = 0;

audio.addEventListener("ended", function() {
   countSongs++
   $('#mp3Source').attr('src', src+countSongs.toString()).detach().appendTo(audio);
   audio.play();
});

$('#mp3Source').error(function() {
   alert("error");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this. Getting the native DOM element as jQuery knows nothing about **.play()** method on the wrapped array returned by the $('#audio') selector:

```
var audio = $("#audio");
var src = "audio/song_";
var countSongs = 0;

audio.addEventListener("ended", function() {

   countSongs++

   $('#mp3Source').attr('src', src + countSongs.toString()).detach().appendTo(audio);
   audio[0].play();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be a little confused regarding jQuery objects and DOM elements?

`$('#audio')` probably doesn't have an `addEventListener` method or a `play` method, so I'm suprised if that works at all ?

I would suggest something more like

```
var audio      = $("#audio");
var src        = "audio/song_";
var countSongs = 0;

audio.on({
    ended: function() {
        $('#mp3Source').prop('src', src + (++countSongs))
                      .detach()
                      .appendTo(audio);
        this.load();
        this.play();
    },
    error: function(e) {
        alert( JSON.stringify(e) ); // for no console
        $(this).off('ended');
    }
});
```